# $p(x)=x^3+6x^2+wx-4$ have the same remainder when it is divided by $x+2$ and $x-1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

For what value of $w$ will the polynomial $p(x)=x^3+6x^2+wx-4$ have the same remainder when it is divided by $x+2$ and $x-1$?

Comment: Try [Polynomial remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Recall that the remainder of the division of $p(x)$ by $x-a$ is $p(a)$. So solve: $$p(-2) = p(1) \implies (-2)^3+6\cdot (-2)^2 - 2w-4 = 1+6+w-4.$$

Answer (score 2):

$x=1$ -> remainder=$1+6+w-4=3+w$

$x=-2$ -> remainder=$-8+24-2w-4=12-2w$

$12-2w=3+w$ -> $w=3$